# Is block reward for mining on a non-currency blockchain necessary?

Tags: blockchain

I am new to blockchain world and working on my final year project of Decentralized E-voting using blockchain. I have another question:

Can I use the devices(that will be used for voting at the polling station) for validation/mining?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

"Blockchain" was invented as a way for a distributed network of computers to agree on data [1](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf). But, blockchain by itself just means a chain of blocks, which is just a data structure. Without a consensus mechanism, it is not really that interesting or useful. The [proof of work](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_work) consensus mechanism used in Bitcoin requires a minimum amount of computation to be done on the block before it is considered according to network rules. This provides distributed consensus because in order for a change to be made to a past block in the blockchain, more work must be done that was previously done in order to change it, so it would require a majority of computation (see [51% Attacks](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Majority_attack)). This attack is deterred by providing an economic incentive (in the form of tokens) for miners, who should find it more profitable to mine than to attack the network, and damage the security and value of their coins.

I suggest you read the [Bitcoin Whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf), and learn about the problem blockchain was designed to solve. For e-voting, more consideration must be made beyond the immutability and consensus mechanism including the incentive to attack the network. What incentives would participants have to support vs attack the ledger of votes, and what would it take to do that. This includes mining, which, don't forget, is an ongoing capital expense in the form of hardware, real estate, and energy costs.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for voting will be to use a Graphene (Bitshares 1.0 and Bitshares-Core-2.0) and POS based blockchain. Followmyvote.com is the best example out there.

The reasoning for POS is that its the most efficient blockchain implementation out there. If you find it difficult to follow the Graphene code, SSBC aka secure scuttle but can give an easy alternative.

For complicated elections, eosDAC is worth exploring.